# how to calculate "FocalLenIn35mmFilm" with limited metadata

Tags: metadata, focal-length, 35mm, crop-factor

Im creating an app that uses "FocalLenIn35mmFilm" to calculate feild of view(FOV). unfortunately not all photographs contain this property in their meta data, the Motorola Nexus 6 is an example. The crop factor is missing too, which could be used multiply it by the focal length. Here is a screen shot of the data i have:

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sensor (SONY IMX214) diagonal is 5.867 mm (~1/3").

```
crop factor = diagonal of the 35mm frame / diagonal of the sensor = 43.3 mm / 5.867 mm = 7.38
FocalLenIn35mmFilm = focal length * crop factor = 3.82 mm * 7.38 = 28mm
```

Comment: While I agree this is correct, is there any way to work this information out solely from the metadata?

Comment: @Philip Kendall : I have not seen full metadata for this file (source, not through Picasa) - I have to have the source file to know. However for our own programs we keep sensor (size) database in case some necessary data is missing in metadata.

Comment: [source file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9IyIJcyctDfSlZtYXhaaG4xT3c/view?usp=sharing). so without knowing the image sensor information(not in metadata) theres no way to work out the FocalLenIn35mmFilm?

Comment: @edward : Thank you, looked at the file - no useful data for calculation of effective focal length from actual focal length. However, the exif mentions Picasa. Are you sure the file is straight out of camera, not modified in any way?

Comment: @lliah does Picasa typically strip metadata? This is what the user gave us. getting originals requires them to transfer to desktop manually, so difficult. Is the sensor size database open source? If so we have a work-around

Comment: @edward : I saw some sites with quite extensive and accurate sensor size data in open access. I really do not know if Picasa copies the metadata block in full (we deal with raw files mostly, out of camera). Now, I do not have direct from the camera samples from this model, but previous Motorola phones were not recording anything but what your sample contains. Re Picasa I think Phil Harvey is the person to ask - http://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/index.html#contact

Comment: @IliahBorg thanks, that's made the picture (no pun intended) clearer and thanks for the above formula which would have taken me hours of hunting round the Internet to work out! The reality is our app will be dealing with limited metadata, so if I can find a regularly updated database of camera sensor sizes that would be ideal, but guess I might have to collate it myself